# Difference between Apex Heap Size and JSON heap size

Tags: webservices, json, governorlimits, heap

Helllo,

I am getting a specific error of "JSON string exceeds heap size limit" . I can not find reference specific to JSON related to heap size.

I know we have Email Heap size of 36 MB, while normal heap size is 6MB synchronous. BTW, this error is coming during a web service callout and I am trying to send lots of data using web service.

My question is Is this same as the total heap size or JSON have some specific heap size in salesforce which I am hitting?

Reference - [Getting heap size error while serializing collection of records in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50258/getting-heap-size-error-while-serializing-collection-of-records-in-apex)

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Salesforce tends to refer to SOAP calls as web services, and REST calls as REST services. You're getting a JSON error, so I assume you're trying to use REST? Could you include some code near where the code is crashing?

Comment: I don't know what the limit is, but i've seen `JSON.serialise()`blow up when you're trying to serialise a (too) large object which is what i guess is happening here.

Comment: Yes it is when I am trying to JSON.serialize() a large structure. And also @sfdcfox , It is in REST only.

Comment: The doiubt I am having is it the same limit of 6MB which is getting exceeded.? And also How I can check the limit so that code can be handled accordingly.

Comment: @KaushikRay : Were you able to handle this ?

Comment: @KaushikRay - Were you guys able to handle this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: we distributed the web service to some extent so that we were able to distribute the data in chunks and handle this exception